# SSAS webservice msmdpump.dll return error on 'OPTIONS'

Tags: sql, kendo-ui, ssas, xmla, pivot-grid

I am having trouble getting a response from SSAS web service "http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll" in kendo pivot grid. 
The thrown error is

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body><soap:Fault xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<faultcode>XMLAnalysisError.0xc10e0002</faultcode><faultstring>Parser: The 
syntax for 'OPTIONS' is incorrect.</faultstring><detail>
<Error ErrorCode="3238920194" Description="Parser: The syntax for 'OPTIONS' is incorrect." Source="Unknown" HelpFile=""/></detail></soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

I checked cros multiple time and service address successfully work with excel.

Comment: I've having the exact same problem. I don't believe it has anything to do with Kendo, because I'm getting the same thing using DevExpress' pivot grid. It has to be some kind of configuration issue, but I'm going mad trying to figure out what, as I followed all the instructions for setting up msmdpump.dll. Did you manage to figure out what the issue was for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found my solution. A handler for options header should add to webservice setting. It's easier to do it in your web.config.


It's not not mandatory for all controls but atlease kendo ui pivot grid and devexpress pivotgrid need this configuration to work.